# javascript add duration to given time

Tags: javascript

I'm writing javascript code from scratch that should add time to current time.
I have declared three variables: h - hours, min - minutes, truk - duration (minutes).

```js
let h = +prompt("Enter current hour: ");
let min = +prompt("Enter current minutes: ");
let truk = +prompt("Enter duration (minutes): ");

let min1 = truk % 60; // We get minutes from duration
let h1 = Math.trunc(truk / 60); // We get hours from duration

console.log("You have entered: " + "h = " + h + ", " + "min = " + min + ", " + "truk = " + truk);
console.log("Result: " + (h + h1) + " : " + (min + min1)); // Don't know how to proceed further with this.
```

For example if we enter hours 17 and minutes 35 and duration 20 it should print out 17:55

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: Whats your goal in the end? What do you want the output to be? Your question is unclear.

Comment: added more details

Comment: OK, what's wrong with this code? What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: I need it to be printed out in correct format.

Comment: What does it print? Please state all of your errors.

Comment: No errors, but if I enter 23 and minutes 30 and duration 45, it gives me 23:75 - it should be 00:15

Answer (score 2):

```js
let h = +prompt("Enter current hour: ");
let min = +prompt("Enter current minutes: ");
let truk = +prompt("Enter duration (minutes): ");

let min1 = truk % 60; // We get minutes from duration
let h1 = Math.trunc(truk / 60); // We get hours from duration

console.log("You have entered: " + "h = " + h + ", " + "min = " + min + ", " + "truk = " + truk);
//without if
var result1 = new Date(2021, 0, 1, h, min, 00, 000); //set time according to user inputs
result1.setMinutes(result1.getMinutes() + truk); //add minutes to set time
console.log("Result: " + (result1.getHours()) + " : " + (result1.getMinutes()));
```

you need to check if minutes are going over 60. If yes then add an hour to existing hrs. Same logic must be applied if hrs are going beyond 24.
Try this :

```
let h = +prompt("Enter current hour: ");
let min = +prompt("Enter current minutes: ");
let truk = +prompt("Enter duration (minutes): ");

let min1 = truk % 60; // We get minutes from duration
let h1 = Math.trunc(truk / 60); // We get hours from duration

console.log("You have entered: " + "h = " + h + ", " + "min = " + min + ", " + "truk = " + truk);
let min_final = 0
let hr_final = h
if((min + min1) > 60){
  min_final = (min + min1) - 60
  hr_final = hr_final + 1
}
hr_final = hr_final + h1
if(hr_final >= 24){
  hr_final = 24 - hr_final
}
if(hr_final < 10){
  hr_final = "0" + hr_final
}
console.log("Result: " + (hr_final) + " : " + (min_final));
```

Comment: I need to do it without if statements.

Comment: "*I need to do it without if statements*" Sorry, but ***what?*** What exactly gives rise to such an insane requirement that you cannot use a **logic gate** that's built-in as part of a language? Why isn't this detailed in your original question?

Comment: My bad, I should've mentioned it in my question.

Comment: Can we use "if" statement for formatting the result? @RalfStrauss

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but you need to consider some additional factors:

1. You need to use the remainder operator `%` again to ensure that the values you return back are base-24 (for hours) and base-60 (for minutes).
2. You also need to consider the updated "hours" value in this scenario is not just the current hour plus the number of hours in the duration you provide, but *also* if the duration causes the minutes to overflow past 60 as well (for instance, a duration of `10` at `17:55` should return `18:05`, not `17:05`).
3. Finally, most locales express minutes with a leading zero when the value is less than `10` - a bit of string manipulation with [`String.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) can go a long way in this scenario.

```js
let h = +prompt("Enter current hour: ");
let min = +prompt("Enter current minutes: ");
let truk = +prompt("Enter duration (minutes): ");

let newMin = ('0' + (min + (truk % 60)) % 60).substr(-2);
let newH = (h + Math.trunc((truk + min) / 60) + Math.trunc(truk / 60)) % 24;

console.log("You have entered: " + "h = " + h + ", " + "min = " + min + ", " + "truk = " + truk);
console.log("Result: " + newH + " : " + newMin);
```

Comment: I tried running your code, but something is wrong -- when I enter h - 18, min - 30 and truk - 60, it gives me this result 20 : 30 - it should be 19 : 30.